# Why does $\left\{\left|X-\sum_{i=1}^mX_i\right|\le\delta\right\}$ depend only on $X_i,i\ge m+1$, if all $X_i$ are independent?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

### Assumptions

Let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of independent real-valued random variables and $$B_{m,n}:=\left\{\left|X^{(i)}-X^{(n)}\right|\le2\delta \text{ for all }i\in[n,m-1]\text{ and }\left|X^{(m)}-X^{(n)}\right|>2\delta\right\}$$ where $$X^{(n)}:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$$
and $\delta>0$. Moreover, let $X^{(n)}$ converge stochastically to some $X$.

---

### Problem

I've read that

1. $B_{m,n}$ depends only on $X_{n+1},\ldots,X_m$ and
2. $\left\{\left|X-X^{(m)}\right|\le\delta\right\}$ depends only on $X_i,i\ge m+1$

---

### My Ideas

I absolutely don't understand why (1) and (2) are true. Especially (2) seems to be counter-intuitively. Shouldn't $\left\{\left|X-X^{(m)}\right|\le\delta\right\}$ depend only on $X_1,\ldots,X_m$?

Comment: What do you mean by "$\{|X-X^{(m)}| \leq \delta\}$ depends only $X_i, i \geq m+1$"? That the event is contained in the sigma-algebra $\sigma(X_i, i \geq m+1)$?

Comment: @saz I mean that $\left\{\left|X-X^{(m)}\right|\le\delta\right\}$ is independent of $X_1,\ldots,X_m$, i.e. independent of $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_m).$

Comment: @oxbadfood  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By definition, $$|X^{(i)}-X^{(n)}| = \left|\sum_{j=n+1}^i X_j \right|$$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_{n+1},\ldots,X_i) \subseteq \sigma(X_{n+1},\ldots,X_{m})$ for all $i \in  \{n,\ldots,m\}$. Therefore, $$B_{m,n} = \bigcap_{i=n}^{m-1} \{|X^{(i)}-X^{(n)}| \leq 2\delta\} \cap |X^{(m)}-X^{(n)}|>2\delta\} \in \sigma(X_{n+1},\ldots,X_m).$$
2. Fix $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $X^{(n)} \to X$ in probability, there exists a subsequence $(X^{(n_k)})_k$ such that $X^{(n_k)} \to X$ almost surely. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $n_k = k$ for all $k \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$. Hence, $$X = \lim_{k \to \infty} X^{(n_k)} = X^{(m)}+ \underbrace{\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{j=m+1}^{n_k} X_j}_{=:Y}.$$ Since $Y$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_{i}; i \geq m+1)$, we get that $Y=X-X^{(m)}$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_i; i \geq m+1)$. As $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of independent random variables, we conclude that $X-X^{(m)}$ is independent from $\sigma(X_i; i \leq m)$.

Comment: I think your second centered equation should be $$\lim_{k\to\infty}X^{(n_k)}=X^{(m)}+\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=m+1}^{n_k}X_i \text{   }\;\;\;\text{almost surely}$$ and in your first sentence, it should be "$\sigma(X_{n+1},\ldots,X^{(i)})$"

Comment: Why can we assume that $n_k=k$ for all $k\in\left\{1,\ldots,m\right\}?$

Comment: @oxbadfood Yeah, there was a typo in the second equation. However, the first sentence is correct as it is written in my answer. Concerning $n_k=k$: Just think of a sequence $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The convergence of this sequence does *not* depend on $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ for any fixed number $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect. I don't think that you mean the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_n\underbrace{+1},\ldots$

Comment: @oxbadfood Sorry, some brackets were missing. Nevertheless, I mean $\sigma(X_{n+1},\ldots,X_i)$ and *not* $\sigma(X_{n+1},\ldots,X^{(i)})$.

Comment: Now, that was a typo of me ;)